# Setting objects equal to one another from different classes

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to figure out how to set an objects from two different classes equal to one another using pointers (see bold in code). The private members of class1 (a,b) should be assigned the value pointed to by class2 members (x,y).

I tried using friend but I'm not sure that's the correct way to assign the members.

```
using namespace std;

class Class1
{
private: int a;
        int b;

};
class Class2
{
private: int *x;
int *y;

};


int main() {

    Class2 Object2;
    **Class1 Object1 = Object2;**
    return 0;
}
```

This would just need to execute without errors.

Comment: So you want `Class2::x` to point to `Class1::a`? Your code would probably make more sense if your `Class2` had a constructor which took a `Class1&`

Comment: No I need the value that x points to to be assigned to a.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to reduce your example to the minimum required to demonstrate this. So let's say we have the following two classes:

```
class A {
    int x = 1;
    friend class B;
};

class B {
    int y = 2;
};
```

We've said that `B` is a friend of `A` and can therefore access it's internals:

```
int main(){
    A a;
    B b;
    b.y = a.x;
}
```

You might think this would work, and this is likely what you tried; however, we're trying to access `a.x` from within `main`, and `main` is *not* a friend of `A`. You can only access the internals of `A` from either `A` or `B`, so that's what we'll do:

```
class B {
    int y = 2;
    void set(const A& a) { y = a.x; }
};
```

Now we give `B` the `A` and it can access `x`, and so now we just call `b.set(a);`. The fact you're using pointers makes no difference here, you just need to dereference them as you normally would.

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to Tas's answers, if you want the syntactic sugar of using the `=` operator, you can overload this operator within your Class1 to do the same thing as `set`.

```
Class1& operator=(const Class2& _other)
{
  y = a.x;

  return *this;
}
```

Where you use it as such:

```
int main() {

  Class2 Object2;
  Class1 Object1;

  Object1 = Object2; 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Except the code shown doesn't use any `operator=` at all. `Class1 Object1 = Object2;` needs a converting constructor. `Class1 Object1; Object1 = Object2;` would be an assignment and would call this `operator=`.

Comment: oops my bad. Fixed now.